# UIButtonのoutletは接続できるのにactionだけ使用できない

Tags: swift, xcode

XCodeのStoryboardでUIButtonを配置し、swiftのコードに青い線を接続しようとしているのですが
outletは接続できるのに、actionが接続できません。

具体的には、以下の動画のようになります。
Connectionに「Outlet」と「Outlet Connection」は出てきますが、actionは出てきません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

actionから線を伸ばそうとすると、swiftファイルは反応せず
outletから線を伸ばすとswiftファイルが反応します。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何が原因だと考えられますか？

Comment: タイトル`test button`のタイプが`Button_Custom`となっていますが、クラス`Button_Custom`は、ほんとうに`UIButton`を継承しているのか？が、最初にチェックすべきことと思います。いかがでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！UIButtonを継承しているかどうかというのは、どこを見れば確認できるのでしょうか？InspectorのTraitsという場所の"Button"にはチェックが入っていました。ButtonのTypeを試しにSystemにも変えてみましたが変化なく、actionは接続できませんでした。

Comment: 「どこを見れば確認できるの」か、という話ではありません。プログラマである質問者さん自身が、`UIButton`のサブクラスを作成した覚えがあるかどうかの話なんです。それと、オブジェクトのタイプ（`Int`、`String`、`UIView`などの「型」）と、「ボタンのタイプ」を取り違えてますので、そこも指摘しておきます。

Comment: カスタムボタン用にswiftファイルを作ってUIButtonを継承したら出来ました、ありがとうございます。いつもはButton_Customを使用せずにSystemボタンを使用していて、そちらでは特にswiftファイルを作らずともaction接続できたような気がしていたのでちょっとまだ頭が混乱している面はありますが無事解決できました。